# Access to Postgres DB within container not working from localhost

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Below is my docker-compose file. I'm not sure what I'm missing. But I'm not able to connect to the postgres from my localhost

````
    dev_db:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - ./db_data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      expose:
        - "5432"
      ports:
        - "5433:5432"
      healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5
      logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "100m"
          max-file: "3"```

psql cmd fom loclhost 

``` sitharamk$ psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -W
Password: 
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5433?```
````

Comment: could you run `docker ps` and copy the container information of postgresql container into your question?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo CONTAINER ID |   IMAGE                       |    COMMAND                  |  CREATED                |  PORTS                    98ed2e396dbf  |  saaswatch-app:dev|  "bash provisioning/e…"   |About an hour ago |  0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp 
40801b358f05  |  postgres                   |   "docker-entrypoint.s…" |  About an hour ago|  5432/tcp

Comment: I think you should update it on your answer so that it won't be turned to ...

Comment: `docker ps` output should have `0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp` under PORTS. So the problem could be with your port mapping. Is 5433 open by any other processes or containers? I tried your compose file and it worked just fine for me. So may be try bringing it down and start up again.

Comment: `About an hour ago| 5432/tcp`, something went wrong. it should be like @Jayachandran mentioned above. `0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp`

Comment: I had a hunch on it and retried multiple times too and also deleted the image as well . Doesn't seem to change the port behavior for Postgres. @Jayachandran same compose worked?

Comment: Yes, same compose (I removed the volume mapping) worked for me. I tried it on a Mac. What does `docker logs <container id>` tell you? I pulled the latest image. You might have an older version.

Comment: Can you bring down the compose and run `docker run --name test-postgres  -d -p 5433:5432 postgres` and see if the port is mapped?

Comment: oh, are you using Linux-based or Unix-based OS or Windows?

Comment: @Jayachandran  container from docker run connected just fine. Took that down and re-run the docker-compose got below logs in docker logs

Comment: listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-10-05 18:25:06.791 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-10-05 18:10:18 UTC
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
redo starts at 0/1899218
 invalid record length at 0/1899250: wanted 24, got 0
 redo done at 0/1899218
 database system is ready to accept connecti

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I'm running docker on mac

Comment: Got it sort , had my fusion(vm) running . caused to use of the port or something.

Comment: "Is 5433 open by any other processes or containers?", I had asked. Glad your problem is resolved.

Comment: Yes, some process within VM. Turned off the VM and tried, it worked

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
  expose:
    - "5432"
  ports:
    - "5433:5432"
```

you need only

```
  ports:
    - "5433:5432"
```

Comment: Yes, but the extra expose won't hurt. At least on my Mac it doesn't.

Comment: @Jayachandran -- Yes, that didn't make any difference. Still same error